# A String manipulation Question for .NET

Tags: c#, .net

How can i remove just first comma + space from below if its there else do nothing.

```
string comments = ", 38, ";
```

Comment: Will the `, ` always appear at the head of the string? Will you see strings **without** a `, `? What do you want to do if you see something like ` 38, 39`?

Comment: Seems you doesnt understand my question. "comma + space from below if its there" => if its there "else" => do nothing.

Comment: seems like you don't understand **my** questions, otherwise you would have answered them.

Comment: @Michael, If you understood his initial question you wouldn't be getting offended :)

Comment: @Marlon: you're right, I didn't understand his original question. It's poorly specified and incomplete. I'm not a mind reader; wish I was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if( comments.StartsWith(", ") && comments.Length > 2 ) {
  comments = comments.Substring(2);
}
```

Comment: This will fail if the string is only ", ", since position 3 does not exist.

Comment: And will also give the wrong result if the string starts with just a comma or a space. ",38, " will turn into "8,".

Comment: @Paw I don't think so, since ",38, " does not start with ", "

Comment: @Mystere Added a check for length based on your comment.

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to use the `String.TrimStart(...)` method.

```
string comments = ", 38, ";
string commentsOK = "38, ";

string trimmedComments = comments.TrimStart(',', ' ');
string trimmedCommentsOK = commentsOK.TrimStart(',', ' ');
```

After this both `trimmedComments` and `trimmedCommentsOK` would have the value `"38, "`.

`String.TrimStart` method reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx

Comment: Wouldn't that also remove " ," from " ,38, "? The TrimStart method is designed to remove all leading chars specified in the arguments, regardless of their order. Based on the question I think you're incorrectly applying TrimStart.

Comment: Well normally you'd want to remove the commas & spaces from before the data and not specifically the string ", ". The issue with the question is the desired output isn't specified.